# Can I dispatch another rtk query from queryFn and await it before continuing?

Tags: redux-toolkit

Essentially I want to await a bunch of queries before resolving a queryFn. An example of this is as follows:

**What I know I can do currently**

I'm aware I can do the following however this looks like it could get messy for more complex examples.

```js
    queryFn: async (
        { emailAddress, password },
        { dispatch },
        _,
        baseQuery,
      ) => {
        await cognito.login(emailAddress, password)
        const { data, error } = await baseQuery({
          url: `me`,
          method: 'GET',
        })
        await dispatch(
          userService.util.updateQueryData('getUser', {}, (draft) => {
            draft = data
          }),
        )
        return { data, error }
      },
```

**What I'd like to do**

Doing the following would mean I don't have to updateQueryData and duplicate endpoint URLs. Also it would mean that I can use errors from other queries to determine if the whole process went as planned.

```js
      queryFn: async (
        { emailAddress, password },
        { dispatch },
      ) => {
        await cognito.login(emailAddress, password)
        const {data,error} = dispatch(userService.endpoints.getUser.initiate({ }, { forceRefetch })) // await this
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was more simple than I'd thought

```js
 login: builder.mutation<{}, Req['login']>({
      queryFn: async ({ emailAddress, password }, { dispatch }) => {
        await Promise.resolve() // do stuff like hit cognito, an api ect
        return dispatch(
          userService.endpoints.getUser.initiate({}, { forceRefetch: true }),
        )
      },
    }),

    getUser: builder.query<Res['user'], Req['getUser']>({
      queryFn: async (args, _, _2, baseQuery) => {
        throw 'Hi i am an error'
      },
    }),
```

```js
  // this becomes {message:"Hi I am an error"} proving it's awaited
  const [login, { error, data }] = useLoginMutation({})
```